# Is there an English translation of the Abhidhamma?

Tags: theravada, abhidhamma

I wonder if there is an English version of the Abhidhamma, in its entirety?

Comment: Incedentally, ive found if you type into a search engine; (name or subject of book) followed by PDF you can find almost anything. This goes for anything from scholarly text books to religious texts.
you may have to scroll and investigate more than the first link to find the most conducive version to suit your needs. heres a few of my most used sites for finding texts. almost ever search for one leads me to one of these.
www.buddhistelibrary.org/
www.accesstoinsight.org/
www.buddhanet.net/

Comment: Very useful bibliography on Buddhist literature: http://faculty.washington.edu/kpotter/ckeyt/home.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no single compiled translation of all the volumes of the *Abhidhamma* but they are separately translated by several people.

You can find an index of these translations in [ATI's Abhidhamma Page](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/abhi/).

Note that, although no English translation of the "The Book of Pairs" (*Yamaka*) is mentioned in the above link, there is one. You can find Vol.1 [here](http://tinyurl.com/ltk4ar3).

[Abhidhamma.com](http://www.abhidhamma.com/index.html) also has useful material available for download, including "The Book of Pairs Vol.2".

Answer (score 1):

There is a  global non-profit initiative aiming at translating the whole [Kangyur and Tengyur](http://84000.co/facts-and-figures-about-kangyur-and-tengyur) (Abhidhamma is a part of Tengyur) into modern languages - [84000](http://84000.co/). You can browse their website to see how they work, what is their vision and which texts has been already translated into English.

Overall, there is not much translated at the moment but they hope that within 10 years a substantial amount of texts will become publicly available in English.

Comment: Abhidhamma is not part of Tengyur.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the abhidhamma pitaka has been translated by the PTS:

http://www.palitext.com/palitext/tipitaka.htm

Translations are as follows:

Buddhist Manual of Psychological Ethics - Dhammasaṅgaṇī

The Book of Analysis - Vibhaṅga

Discourse on Elements - Dhātukathā

Points of Controversy - Kathāvatthu

Designation of Human Types - Puggalapaññatti

Conditional Relations - Paṭṭhāna

The only one that is missing is the Yamaka, for which I see there are a couple of partial translations as mentioned in another answer.

Comment: thank you. Any chance that there are digital versions of these volumes, available?

Comment: I think the scans are kicking around; scribd.com has them, I think.